# Using constants as indices for JavaScript associative arrays

Tags: javascript, constants, associative-array

I'm looking to create an associative array in JavaScript, but use constants defined as part of the class as indices.

The reason I want this is so that users of the class can use the constants (which define events) to trigger actions.

Some code to illustrate:

```
STATE_NORMAL = 0;
STATE_NEW_TASK_ADDED = 0;
this.curr_state = STATE_NEW_TASK_ADDED;

this.state_machine = {
    /* Prototype:
    STATE_NAME: {
        EVENT_NAME: {
            "next_state": new_state_name,
            "action": func
        }
    }
    */

    STATE_NEW_TASK_ADDED : { // I'd like this to be a constant
        this.EVENT_NEW_TASK_ADDED_AJAX : {
            "next_state": STATE_NEW_TASK_ADDED,
            "action" : function() {console.log("new task added");},
        }
    }
}

// Public data members.
// These define the various events that can happen.
this.EVENT_NEW_TASK_ADDED_AJAX = 0;
this.EVENT_NEW_TASK_ADDED_AJAX = 1;
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm not too great with JavaScript, but it looks like no matter what I do, the array gets defined with strings and not constants. Is there a way to force the array to use the constants?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

See [Kristian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117214/using-constants-as-indices-for-javascript-associative-arrays/35725376#35725376) re: ECMAScript 6/modern JavaScript, which has new syntax to make this possible.

The below is my original answer, from the pre-modern age.

---

The problem here, actually, is that you can't use a value for the key part when you're defining an object **literally**.

That is to say, this uses the constant values as expected:

```js
var CONSTANT_A = 0, CONSTANT_B = 1;
var state_machine = {};
state_machine[CONSTANT_A] = "A";
state_machine[CONSTANT_B] = "B";
console.log(state_machine[0]); // => A
console.log(state_machine[1]); // => B
```

But this won't work as expected, instead using the string `CONSTANT_A` as key:

```js
var CONSTANT_A = 0, CONSTANT_B = 1;
var state_machine = {
    CONSTANT_A: "A",
    CONSTANT_B: "B",
};
console.log(state_machine[0]); // => undefined
console.log(state_machine["CONSTANT_A"]); // => A
console.log(state_machine.CONSTANT_A); // => A
```

JavaScript has a shorthand to define object literals where you can omit the double-quotes around keys. Expressions can't be used, so `CONSTANT_A` won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 64):

In ECMAScript 6 you can use computed values for object keys:

```js
var CONSTANT_A = 0, CONSTANT_B = 1
var state_machine = {
    [CONSTANT_A]: function () {
        return 'a'
    },
    [CONSTANT_B]: function () {
        return 'b'
    }
};

console.log(state_machine)
```

This does not work in Internet Explorer 11 nor in Safari browsers:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Ah, ES6 is so great

Answer (score 24):

Let's say you have the following constants:

```js
const COMPANIES = "companies";
const BRANCHES = "branches";
const QUEUES = "queues";
const LOGOUT = "logout";
```

If you declare the dictionary this way:

```js
var itemsToState = {
  COMPANIES: true,
  BRANCHES: false,
  QUEUES: false,
  LOGOUT: false,
}

// You will get:
// { COMPANIES: true, BRANCHES: false, QUEUES: false, LOGOUT: false }
```

Note the keys are uppercase ^ because **it is not using the constant's value.**

If you want to use the constant's value as key, you need to do this:

```js
var itemsToState = {
  [COMPANIES]: true,
  [BRANCHES]: false,
  [QUEUES]: false,
  [LOGOUT]: false,
}

// You will get:
// { companies: true, branches: false, queues: false, logout: false }
```

Note the keys are lowercase ^ because **it is using the constant's value.**

Comment: The examples make the code and answer easy to understand. Thanks!