# How to create javascript object with custom name?

Tags: javascript

It's a little bit difficult to explain what I need, so I'll use some non-working code:

```
function createSimpleObjet(name, value){
    return {
        name: value
    };
}

//create it
var obj = createSimpleObject('Message', 'Hello World!');
//test it:
alert(ojb.Message); //should alert 'Hello World!'
```

How would I go about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create object using variables for property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153969/create-object-using-variables-for-property-name)

Comment: See also [Using constants as indices for JavaScript associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117214/using-constants-as-indices-for-javascript-associative-arrays/4117231#4117231).

Comment: Yeah, I see. Really difficult to search where you are looking when one doens't know how do call it :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to do this try [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html):

```
function createSimpleObject(name, value){
    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a variable as a property name in an object literal. You have to create the object, and then assign the value using square bracket notation.

```
var object = {};
object[name] = value;
```